# skaffold init with helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold

I'm trying to perform `skaffold init`. I'm getting this message:

> FATA[0000] one or more valid Kubernetes manifests is required to run skaffold

I guess `skaffold` is looking for kubernetes manifests. However, I'm using helm charts in order to run and deploy my artifacts on kubernetes.

I mean, I don't have and will not have any `"valid"` kubernetes manifest since I'm using helm charts.

How could I proceed with init?

Comment: Could you please share your skaffold.yaml file , you might be missing your helm-chart path innside it.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, it is not possible to generate skaffold.yaml file through skaffold init when we want deployment through helm. But, Skaffold does support Helm for deployment. We can manually create skaffold.yaml file and update the deployment section based on the options available for helm.

Also note that we need to update image and pullpolicy in deployment.yaml, and few changes in values.yaml.

Source - [No support for Skaffold init --helm](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/3768)

[Helm support for Helm as deployment strategy](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/deployers/helm/)